# Unable to uninstall macport on Snowleopard

Tags: macos, macports

I installed from the installer available for snowleopard at their download page. I am new to this.. and I found homebrew a better alternative. So, Now I am trying to remove it completely.

```
sudo port -fp uninstall installed
```

I get:

```
Error: No ports matched the given expression
```

When I try

```
sudo port uninstall installed
```

I am getting the following message.

```
Can't map the URL 'file://.' to a port description file ("Could not find Portfile in /Users/Shashank").
Please verify that the directory and portfile syntax are correct.
To use the current port, you must be in a port's directory.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Appreciate any information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands you are issuing remove the installed ports. You should delete the folders manually to complete the installation:

Use these commands:

Note:

The installation folders may differ from those listed below depending on your installation

```
%% sudo rm -rf \
    /opt/local \
    /Applications/DarwinPorts \
    /Applications/MacPorts \
    /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \
    /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \
    /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
    /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
    /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
    /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
    ~/.macports
```

Comment: did that. But seems like the port command still works, when i enter 'port'

Comment: Are you sure you remove the correct folders? The folders where it is installed may differ depending on your installation

Comment: dev:usr Shashank$ sudo rm -rf \
> >     /opt/local \
> >     /Applications/DarwinPorts \
> >     /Applications/MacPorts \
> >     /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \
> >     /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \
> >     /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
> >     /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
> >     /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
> >     /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
> >     ~/.macports
-bash: /opt/local: Is a directory
dev:usr Shashank$ port
MacPorts 2.1.3
Entering interactive mode... ("help" for help, "quit" to quit)
[/usr] >

Comment: ok.. i see the deletion didnt work.. thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry first question. Done now.

Thanks again.. :)